# Extract part of a url using pattern matching in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract part of a url using pattern matching in python from a list of links

Examples:

http://www.fairobserver.com/about/
http://www.fairobserver.com/about/interview/

This is my regex :

```
re.match(r'(http?|ftp)(://[a-zA-Z0-9+&/@#%?=~_|!:,.;]*)(.\b[a-z]{1,3}\b)(/about[a-zA-Z-_]*/?)', str(href), re.IGNORECASE)
```

I want to get links ending only with `/about` or `/about/`
but the above regex selects all links with "about" word in it

Comment: Put a `$` at the end.

Comment: Would you also want to match `/interview/about`?

Comment: NO. I want immediate "about" following .com . Like http://www.fb.com/about or http://www.fb.com/about-the-site. None following after "above/" @JoshTriiJohnston

Comment: Thanks, see answer below for a solution to match `/about` or `/about/`

Comment: You could use something like this to only match URLs ending with about, but which might have query params: (.*?about/)?(\?=.*?)?$

Comment: i tried this pattern match  re.match(r'^(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[^:\/\n]+\/about[a-zA-Z-]*[/]?$)', str(Uhref),re.IGNORECASE) . it worked. thanks for your help everyone

Comment: Your question says you want "links ending only with /about or /about/". Your pattern contradicts this description by allowing url path components that start with `/about`. This part of the pattern `\/about[a-zA-Z-]*[/]?$` will allow `/aboutus`, `/about-us/`, `/aboutofthegoutisnotgoodforyou`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you parse your URLs using an appropriate library, e.g. `urlparse` instead.

E.g.

```
import urlparse

samples = [
  "http://www.fairobserver.com/about/",
  "http://www.fairobserver.com/about/interview/",
]

def about_filter(urls):
  for url in urls:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if parsed.path.endswith('/about/'):
      yield url
```

Yielding:

```
>>> print list(about_filter(samples))
['http://www.fairobserver.com/about/']
```

Or

```
def about_filter(urls):
  for url in urls:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if parsed.path.startswith('/about'):
      yield url
```

Yielding

```
>>> print list(about_filter(samples))
['http://www.fairobserver.com/about/', 'http://www.fairobserver.com/about/interview/']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want links ending in either use a html parser and str.endwith:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.fairobserver.com/about/")
print(list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(("/about", '/about/')),
                  (a["href"] for a in BeautifulSoup(r.content).find_all("a", href=True)))))
```

You can also use a regex with BeautifulSoup:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.fairobserver.com/about/")
print([a["href"] for a in BeautifulSoup(r.content).find_all(
     "a", href=re.compile(".*/about/$|.*/about$"))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching the path of exactly `/about/` or `/about` per your comment clarification.
Below is using urlparse in python2/3.

```
try:
    # https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#urllib.parse.urlparse
    # python 3
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    # https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse
    # python 2
    from urlparse import urlparse

urls = (
    'http://www.fairobserver.com/about/',
    'http://www.fairobserver.com/about/interview/',
    'http://www.fairobserver.com/interview/about/',
)

for url in urls:
    print("{}: path is /about? {}".format(url,
          urlparse(url.rstrip('/')).path == '/about'))
```

Here is the output:

```
http://www.fairobserver.com/about/: path is /about? True
http://www.fairobserver.com/about/interview/: path is /about? False
http://www.fairobserver.com/interview/about/: path is /about? False
```

The important part is `urlparse(url.rstrip('/')).path == '/about'`, normalizing the url by stripping off the trailing `/` before parsing so that we don't have to use regex.

Comment: i tried this pattern match re.match(r'^(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[^:\/\n]+\/about[a-zA-Z-]*[/]?$)', str(Uhref),re.IGNORECASE) . it worked